# Source for the Adage: "The first liar is always believed most."

Tags: expressions, popular-refrains

In a couple of books and articles I've come across an adage, “the first liar is always believed most”:

> Now, I talked to the captain first, but I want you to know that great old saying, “The first liar gets believed”, does not apply with me. I listen to everybody the same.
>   —Poyer, David. *[The Gulf](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312925778)*, p. 322.*
>
> And while I agree the digital age gives you additional options for setting the record straight or refuting allegations, there’s another old adage I heard once that seems to be true as well: “the first liar is always believed most.”
>   —Barrett, John. Comment section, “[Is It a Better Time Than Ever to Pick Fights With the Press?](http://www.mrmediatraining.com/2011/10/26/is-it-a-better-time-than-ever-to-pick-fights-with-the-press/)”, *Mr. Media Training Blog*.

Where did this originate?

* Quotation verified using Amazon’s *search inside this book* feature, search text [ first liar ].

Comment: what did a google search tell you?

Comment: @Mitch Not very much.  A couple of people cite it, but generally I get the Christian adage that "the first liar always loses."

Comment: Can you give us a quote for that? It is an awfully clumsy sentence. Are you sure it was not _the first liar is always the most believed_ or similar?

Comment: @terdon -- I took your advice.  See edits.

Comment: I edited to include excerpts in the question. This is helpful because of link rot.

Comment: @MετάEd Thanks Mitch.  Good edit.  Hopefully, others will appreciate the question now and vote it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***The First Liar Wins***: You must be referring to the [FLW Rule](http://www.infoworld.com/d/adventures-in-it/how-expose-empty-office-rhetoric-constructively-218).

> FLW is in effect whenever a conversational combatant asserts a fact, evidence, or conclusion that is (1) simply stated; (2) superficially plausible; and (3) emotionally appealing.

Bob Lewis writes further on InfoWorld:

> It works because once uttered — and because they are simple, plausible, and appealing — any attempt to refute them sounds argumentative rather than constructive.